Remote tunnel view web app while working on code
I am trying to develop a web app via remote tunnel on another computer.
Let's say we have two computers:
Computer A:
with the source code for the laravel app.
Computer B:
my device which I am traveling with.
Normally on computer A I can just run a dev command to be able to view the web app in the browser on a port on the localhost like http://localhost:3000.
I am able to connect computer B to computer A to edit the source code for my web app, but how can I view the web app in the browser to test it?

My question would be: Why this complex way of working if you can use a git repository and work locally on both computers? Other than that, this question is off topic

@GertB. thanks. This is just an example, but there are other instances where I have a web app running some code on the computer A which is more "beefy" compared to my travel laptop.
I don't see how this is off topic because it is related to visual studio code, which is commonly used by developers. Open to suggestions if this belongs somewhere else.

OK, valid argument why this would be on-topic if it is about VSC. However, it is more about the browser, and opening a localhost remotely.  Sail has the option to share your app via Expose with the command sail share. Maybe this is a solution?

Again, this is just an example. I have other non laravel apps too. Also I don't want to expose it to the entire internet. Since VS Code tunnels allows for more secure access, I was thinking this could be a work around to a simpler setup.

I was able to find the solution which is super simple and and provided the answer below for anyone who may find this useful. I also updated the question as this is more broad and not specific to the web app technology used.

I found the solution. The key is to open the remote computer (Computer A) which you have connected via the tunnel in VS Code and use the remote port forwarding (described at: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/port-forwarding) to forward the port on which your app is being served locally on Computer A.
An example from the docs:

This will give you a URL as a forwarded address, which you can use on Computer B or any other device to view the web app. Connecting to this forwarded address in your browser will require the same login as your tunnel thereby being a secure way of accessing it.
